# Asciimath plugin for TinyMCE not creating images

Tags: tinymce

I'm using the Asciimath plugin for TinyMCE (http://www.imathas.com/editordemo/demo.html)
It was working fine until a few moments ago. Now I can see the math notation *just fine* in the editor, but on submitting the form, it's contents do not change to an image replacing the `<span class="AM">` tag that the plugin creates.

Hence the HTML that the editor produces retains the Math-syntax I typed with the span tag and not show the Math notation properly in an image.

If anybody knows how to fix this, please help me. I'm really confused as to why it suddenly stopped working. A server-side text-replacement solution would be great as well.

I have tried this:

```
preg_replace('/\<span class="AM"\>`(.+)`\<\/span\>/', '<img src="http://www.imathas.com/cgi-bin/mimetex.cgi?$1" />', $str)
```

But that results in broken display of the Math fragment since some of the additional parameters like `displaystyle` that the script adds are lost.

**NOTE** I recently switched from regular-TinyMCE to the jQuery plugin TinyMCE. Could this be the reason the plugin is not working? I'm not sure if it broke functionality right after I made this change.

Comment: i strongly suggest not to use the jQuery tinymce build, it is a source of trouble and in addition slowerthan the regular tinymce build

Comment: It's indeed a pain. Unfortunately the standard build is conflicting with the rest of my code since I'm using Asset Compression. Also if the TinyMCE website is to be believed the jQuery build eliminates 'redundant code' and is faster. At any rate, I have fixed this issue with a Eval-flagged Regex. I used the PHP function to convert the string to TeX, provided by the author